# What is the best way for Django microservices intercommunication?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, microservices

I have a django microservice: M1 with admin page having fields:

> [link to field11] | [link to field 21]

I have another django microservice: M2 with admin page having fields:

> field11 | field12 | field13 | field14 | field 15

I have another django microservice: M3 with admin page having fields:

> field21 | field22 | field23 | field24 | field 25

My requirement is to get all the fields of M2 and M3 into M1's admin page.
What are the ways I can do this? I do not want to add more fields into M1's model.

One way is to do interservice communication or do a GET call. What will be more feasible?

Comment: I am not familiar with Django but on a high level a client ("M1 admin page") would call a API gateway which queries the microservices as needed and map the data from the multiple sources into a single response. I am not sure what the equivalence would be in Django.

Answer (score -1):

You can try some thing like this,

```
class M2(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class M3(models.Model):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class M1(M2, M3):
    field = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

So will get the fields of M2, and M3 into the M1, Hope its helps you, if anything else please let me know.+

Comment: The models are in 3 different django apps (/microservices). I don't think that should be done for this scenario

Comment: If so in 3 different apps, you can import it in file and try using abstract/proxy model